# Visual Studio post build events stuck waiting for executable to finish before running app in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

Part of the post build on my project is the execution of a program I wrote for testing the main application. Unfortunately, the post build process in visual studio locks up waiting for the executable to exit. So, i'm stuck closing my test program in order to have the post build process complete and my application run. How do I change this so VS does not wait for the program to return before launching? Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

I also found that the `start` trick didn't work and downloading a separate tool to complete such a simple task seemed excessive. After some additional searching I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914374/visual-studio-build-event-immediately-return) which gave an answer that worked for my needs.

Just replace `<actual-command-line-to-run>` with your command. Remember to give the full path to the executable and encapsulate it in "quotes" if there's spaces in your path.

```
powershell start-process <actual-command-line-to-run>
```

Comment: This worked for me and imho is the best solution as it requires no external tool.

Comment: Same here, the only solution if found that worked without an external tool

Comment: If you are trying to call CMD from the `Start-Process` command with arguments, you need to "double-escape" your quotes - e.g. `powershell start-process "cmd ""/K echo HelloWorld"""`

Comment: After many hours wasted, this actually worked!

Answer (score 10):

Wow, seems VS is really stubborn about this.

You can use this little [tool](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) that can launch apps without showing cmd windows (among other things). In your post build event:

```
c:\path\to\cmdow /run app.exe
```

Comment: This tool WILL run a post build script ASYNCHRONOUSLY!

Comment: Sounds like this is the best solution so far, but requires using a separate tool. I'm looking for a batch command or C# code that would enable such fire & forget command launching from the post build event.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a known issue of VS 2010 (e.g. [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/593873/visual-studio-2010-ui-hangs-during-post-build-actions#details) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/566899/)) and it seems it won't be fixed *that* soon.

Regarding a possible workaround, similar to the one mentioned by @RichieHindle, one of the MS Connect persons suggests:

```
START /WAIT cmd /c YourPostBuildTool.exe
```

Comment: I think this option is better than the powershell version because powershell should not be relied upon being present.

Saying that, I guess these days powershell would facilitate cross platform support.

Answer (score 1):

Running your test program via `start` might work. Change your post build step from this:

```
runtest.exe
```

to this:

```
start runtest.exe
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It just opens the command line. Is the syntax wrong?

    start "$(ProjectDir)DDEClient\program.exe"

original was 

    "$(ProjectDir)DDEClient\program.exe"

Comment: Maybe `cmd /c start "$(ProjectDir)DDEClient\program.exe"` ?

Comment: No luck either. I managed to get it to work by writing a autohotkey script that launchs my application using the Run command. Thanks for your help, though. It was appreciated.

Comment: @max: using `"$(TargetPath)"` with and without `start` or `cmd /c` didn't help. Can you please please share the script for running via Run command?

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize [cruise control](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET) for your builds, you could place this in the publishers section which allows the build to finish before running the publisher tasks.

Additionally a [custom msbuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) is quite trivial to build, if you know how to spin off a process in .net then it's really simple to do in msbuild. To do this you could edit your .csproj file or your .proj build script to use that custom task.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace MyTasks
{
public class SimpleTask : Task
{
    public override bool Execute()
    {
//something involving Process.Start
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Then in your build script or csproj file you add the using for the task you created and call it.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded a patch to MSBuild Extension Pack that implements a custom msbuild task called SmartExec that works around this issue.

http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/workitem/9053
http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches
Patch Id 9878

Answer (score 0):

I spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure this out.  What you need to do is place "cmd" as the first line of your post-build event.

An example might look like this:

```
cmd
xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)$(OutputDir)* C:\SomePath\*
```