# Visual Studio 2010 hangs when executng post-build events

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why Visual Studio 2010 hangs when it executes post-build events? It seems that it is doing them on gui thread. Because of that now i'm placed all instructions in .cmd file so I at least I can see output in realtime and not after build completes. It's supposed to work that way or i'm doing something wrong?

**upd:**
If I place `notepad.exe` into post-build events then Visual Studio will become unresponsive to any user input (and after some time 'Visual Studio is busy' popup appears) until I close notepad. The question is how to make VS responsive (so I can at least click 'output' tab) *while* notepad is running.

Comment: I'm surprised that "start notepad.exe" yields the same problem.   Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356516/visual-studio-post-build-events-stuck-waiting-for-executable-to-finish-before-run

Answer (score 0):

Postbuild events have to work for your compilation to succeed.  Meaning, even if the event is some non project related mechanism that you've thrown in, if it fails, your compilation will fail.  As an example, when building Media Center applications, the standard process is to include a dll that the SDK thinks is in on your system, but in fact has been gone since Vista, so, if you leave the post build event in, you can't even compile your code.

Comment: The question is "How do I kick-off a post-build event without having to wait for it." In other words, whatever command would do this would fork off a process, then report success back through MSBUILD, right?